# Why does poetry install windows only dependency on macOS and linux?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, python-poetry

I have tried listing the following dependency in `pyproject.toml` to have this particular `torch` only be installed when on Windows platforms.

```
torch = { url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.7.0%2Bcpu-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl", platform = "windows"}
```

```
torch = { url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.7.0%2Bcpu-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl", markers = "sys_platform == 'win32'"}
```

Regardless, poetry attempts to install it on macOS and linux, causing an error.

```
  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/home/runner/work/.../.venv/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', '/home/runner/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/00/91/70/1f0b4cacc2e27f6d54a1d33fccf09212bb25b7559f2e5ee8f457902ed6/torch-1.7.0+cpu-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  ERROR: torch-1.7.0+cpu-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

How can `torch` be listed so that it only installs on Windows platforms?

Comment: Why not add (equivalent of) `torch-1.9.0-cp39-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl` if you are on a Mac?

Comment: Adding torch as a dependency on mac/linux doesn't seem to be an issue (Poetry resolves it and everything is fine), it appears that only Windows needs this super specific dependency spec.

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be solved from version 1.2.0b3 as described in this ticket: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1616